# MySQL partition failed

Tags: mysql, partitioning, galera, mysql-cluster

I do partition with 6.595.057 rows in MySQL with the Galera cluster. When I tried partition in server without galera, partition successfull. But when I tried partition in server with galera cluster, partition failed. Here is my script :

```
ALTER TABLE r_absensi partition by range COLUMNS(tgl_absen) (
    partition p2020 values less than ('2021-01-01'),
  partition p2021 values less than ('2022-01-01'),
  partition p202201 values less than ('2022-02-01'),
  partition p202202 values less than ('2022-03-01'),
  partition p202203 values less than ('2022-04-01'),
  partition p202204 values less than ('2022-05-01'),
  partition p202205 values less than ('2022-06-01'),
  partition p202206 values less than ('2022-07-01'),
  partition p202207max values less than (MAXVALUE)
);
```

tgl_absen is a column table with date format. Here is the result for partition in the Galera cluster :
[image]

Comment: What do you get from `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM r_absensi;`?  How many rows used to be in the table?

Comment: i get 6.595.057 rows

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare DATE with string or any other values, the best way to do it assuming the filed type you are using is date is using an embedded function in MySQL TO_DAYS, you need to change the `than ('2021-01-01')` to `than (TO_DAYS('2021-01-01')),` and so on

Comment: I have tried this. In the noncluster database, it works, but in The Galera cluster doesn't work